# Modding Michael Hartl's railstutorial: Where to place rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am playing around with Michael Hartl's [railstutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). I want to limit access to profile pages so only the owner can see his/hers profile. First task is to write the appropriate rspec test, but what is the logical location of this: [user_pages](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb) or [authentication_pages](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably user_pages, though it could easily go in authentication.  I think in this situation, you're best to just write the test and keep going.  If, later, you find it sits better in a different place, move it.

Comment: What is the reasoning if I may ask?

Comment: Because nothing is perfect at the beginning. And in your case it really doesn't matter where you put the test, as long as there is such a scenario in test it is good.

Comment: There is a saying, "You'll never know less that you know now".  So getting focussed on the perfect place to put it stops you writing the test.  If future information arises which shows it should be somewhere else, then move it.  It's all good as long as you make it easy to move the code in the future.